# Widget translation won't work

Tags: magento, widget, translate

I have a module with a custom widget and I need to translate widget name and params
The translation file exists in the module and working for other strings except the widget.
Helper is also exists in the module.
Here is my widget.xml:

```
<widgets>
<current_coupons type="coupons/coupon_widget_current" translate="name description" module="coupons">
    <name>Current Coupons List</name>
    <description>List of Coupons that currently active</description>
    <is_email_compatible>1</is_email_compatible>
    <parameters>
        <coupons_count translate="label">
            <required>1</required>
            <visible>1</visible>
            <value>5</value>
            <label>Number of Coupons to Display</label>
            <type>text</type>
        </coupons_count>
        <coupons_type translate="label">
            <required>1</required>
            <visible>1</visible>
            <value>latest</value>
            <label>Type of the listing (Annonce or Latest)</label>
            <type>select</type>
            <values>
                <latest translate="label">
                    <value>latest</value>
                    <label>Latest</label>
                </latest>
                <annonce translate="label">
                    <value>annonce</value>
                    <label>Annonce</label>
                </annonce>
            </values>
        </coupons_type>
    </parameters>
</current_coupons>
```

Please, help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed by adding  section into  section in the config.xml file.